# Splitting numbers from strings and also splitting joint strings

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have read many posts and have found partial solution to this, it would be great if anyone could help me completely as I am not able to find the solution for this.

I have a sentence which needs to be broken down into the output format. How should that be done?

```
s='Eiffel Tower140,005 reviewsObservation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks'
```

now i want the output like this in 3 parts:

Place name, reviews, detail:

Output:

```
["Eiffel Tower" , "140,005 reviews" ,
 "Observation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks"]
```

Comment: `\'([A-Za-z\s]+)([\d,]+)\s?(.*)\'` - Can you try this ? https://regex101.com/r/02Rqj6/3 . Will it always be in this format ?? If not please give few different examples in order to provide exact regex

Comment: yes the format is going to be same but this doesnt solve. It is giving me output as "Eiffel Tower" , "140,005 ", reviewsObservation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks" which doesnt match required output . 

reviews should be along with 140,005 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `re.split` you can use a capture group to preserve the delimiter (the number of reviews here):

```
re.split(r'(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})* reviews?)', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(.+?)([\d\,]+ reviews)(.*)`
This will group in the following manner.

- Group 1: Match until reach numbers followed by "reviews"
- Group 2: Match numbers (including commas) and " reviews" into a single string
- Group 3: All remaining characters and symbols.

`Eiffel Tower140,005 reviewsObservation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks`

Outputs:

`['Eiffel Tower', '140,005 reviews', 'Observation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks']`

https://regex101.com/r/bDAVNb/2

Comment: Thanks it works but it adds empty string before every  new line. 
using this regex I'm getting :
[' ', 'Eiffel Tower', '140,005 reviews', 'Observation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks', ' '] 
Nevermind, I just removed (.+?) and (.*) from ([\d\,]+ reviews) and it gave me required output.

Answer (score 1):

Just split using `re.split` based on the boundaries between a small letter followed by a number or a capital letter

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=\d|[A-Z])', s)
['Eiffel Tower', '140,005 reviews', 'Observation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks']
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution would only work for this particular sentence and other sentences that follow the same rules. It could be extended to other sentence structures by adding more conditions in the loop. It's a bit easier to read than regex for the uninitiated. It's a little hacky with the indexing, but that's a quick fix on you.

I noticed that the split is happening between letter & number, and lowercase letter & uppercase letter. So you just have to loop through the sentence and define the rules.

```py
s='Eiffel Tower140,005 reviewsObservation Decks & Towers, Points of Interest & Landmarks'

result = []
temp = ''

for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
    current_letter = s[i]
    next_letter = s[i+1]

    if current_letter.islower() and next_letter.isnumeric():
        temp += current_letter
        result.append(temp)
        temp = ''
    elif current_letter.islower() and next_letter.isupper():
        temp += current_letter
        result.append(temp)
        temp = ''
    else:
        temp += current_letter
temp+= s[len(s)-1]
result.append(temp)

print(result)
```